# php $_FILES добавление информации в массив

Tags: php, файлы, fileupload

Возможно ли расширить массив $_FILES, добавив кастомные параметры ? Т.е. к примеру по умолчанию, он выглядит у меня так

```
array(1) {
  ["file"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "image.jpg"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(39) "D:\OpenServer\userdata\temp\phpBBE7.tmp"
    }
    ["error"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["size"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(1092727)
    }
  }
}
```

Можно каким то образом добавить сюда свои параметры(элементы) ?

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Суперглобальный массив `$_FILES` работает на запись и чтение как обычный массив.

Но вопрос в другом: зачем вам такое могло понадобиться?! Лучше уж создайте обертку в виде класса, в конструктор которого передаете `$_FILES` и расширяйте класс как вам надо.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Ну к примеру чтобы можно было передать информацию о изображении(в моем случае), например параметры обрезки, описание и т.д.